# Issue with character set

Tags: java

I have an issue in writing a file to a server path. 
The problem is like this:

I have a job that runs in the Unix environment to get an extract and write that to a file in the server location. The path that I have configured to write the file ..say "abc.csv" is in 
/projects/distrib/extracts/XXX/éxtract.

The problem here is when the file is been created by the job the final folder is created as ?xtract. The é is been converted. But if I try to create the folder with same name manually in the same machine through file zilla the folder gets created.

Could you please help me to identify an correct the issue.

I had tried MimeUtility.encodeText("éxtract"); But didnt work..it encoded the text to something else.

Comment: Could you post the bit of your code that creates the target file or file output stream or writer?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is hard to guess what the cause might be, but you can start by trying this:

1. Make sure that you are compiling your Java class with the correct file encoding. For example, if your source is in UTF-8, then use the `-encoding utf8` flag with `javac`.
2. Confirm the environment variables for the user under which this Java-based process run. For example what do you have for `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_ALL`, etc.